# Format Chart DataLabel in Powershell generated Excel File

Tags: excel, powershell, charts, format

Try to format datalabel font size with a powershell generated barchart, but does not work

Read the "whole" API for Chart.SeriesCollection for VBA and .NET. But it does not help. Is it a bug or have I a brain bug? Anyone who can help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.chart.seriescollection

My try (with different iterations about this)

```
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange2.Font.Size = 18
```

Powershell Error Message: The property 'Size' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

The whole short powershell script:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet = $excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.Activate() | Out-NULL

$sheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2 = "City"
$sheet.Cells.Item(1,2).Value2 = "Citizens"
$sheet.Cells.Item(2,1) = "Offenbach"
$sheet.Cells.Item(2,2) = 111020
$sheet.Cells.Item(3,1) = "Heusenstamm"
$sheet.Cells.Item(3,2) = 18200
$sheet.Cells.Item(4,1) = "Rembruecken"
$sheet.Cells.Item(4,2) = 1850

$range = "A1:B4"
$chartSelect = $sheet.range($range)
$ch = $sheet.shapes.addChart().chart
$ch.chartType = 51

$ch.ApplyDataLabels(2)
$ch.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange2.Font.Size = 18
$ch.setSourceData($chartSelect)
```

Comment: please add more code so we can try to reproduce it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ?

```
1..3| %{$ch.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels($_).Font.Size = 18}
```

Comment: Unbelievable, this WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple syntaxes that ought to work.

The old one which you need to select 'Show hidden members' in the VBIDE's Object Browser to see (as if it's been deprecated, but it works fine):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Font.Size = 18
```

The new and improved and way more complex one:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 18
```

I'll let you convert from VBA to PowerShell.